# where does struct object get memory in main function?

Tags: c++

how does `tmp` get memory from the machine, from heap or stack?

I thought it was from the stack, but it seem that the code can run properly

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct node {
   int a[1000000];
};
int main() {
    node tmp;
    memset(tmp.a, -1, sizeof(tmp.a));
    cout << tmp.a[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile, let alone "run properly".

Comment: The stack.  And it's far to big to be allocated there.

Answer (score 1):

In **stack**, since it's an automatic variable to the main function.

---

PS: This code doesn't compile, for example with this error: `error: type 'node' does not provide a subscript operator: cout << tmp[0];`.

Comment: updated my code, is can compile now